# AS3 - How to prevent flash from quiting?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I got this flash program that loads other swf files into my main timeline and in one of these loaded swf files got an exit button that was created by using the exit fscommand and if I clicked on the exit button it closes my main flash player. I can not change these swf files. So how do you add a prevention so that the program do not quit?

I.E.

```
if (program.exit)
{
  //display a yes/no message before quiting
  if (yes)
  {
    //then quit
  } else
  {
    //do not quit
  }
}
```

Comment: The easy answer is to put a button over the top of the button.  You can set the cursor on your button to not show as a button and do nothing when clicked.

Comment: That is brilliant thinking! I would rather want to do the other way, but this is perfect! Thank you moot!